# How to hide ongoing persistent notifications on Lollipop lockscreen

Tags: 5.0-lollipop

It's driving me nuts seeing those notices each time I open my phone, leaving no room for the transient notifications and messages I've received.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that blocking the notifications by app will also hide the icon in the notification bar when the screen is unlocked. For example, I have a battery app which displays how much juce I have left in percent in the notification bar. When I blocked the notification, it hid it from the lock screen (which is what I wnted), but it also disappeared from the notification bar after I unlocked my phone. I had to restart the app to get the icon back.

Answer (score 2):

Not possible, it seems. There is a thread on XDA about this: http://forum.xda-developers.com/google-nexus-5/help/hide-ongoing-notifications-lockscreen-t2938422

Answer (score 1):

An app called Notific does the job beautifully. It has a pro version which allows you to select which apps you want to show notifications for. It has many more useful customisations too.

[Here's a link to the app](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiF8vGJv4bKAhXIj44KHSdKB50QFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fplay.google.com%2Fstore%2Fapps%2Fdetails%3Fid%3Dcom.anandbibek.notifypro%26hl%3Den&usg=AFQjCNFrtPxztHSgpWif6vqvvk5HN601GQ&sig2=liH6L4fOsHBbb3OtTNkDIA)

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered one way to temporary remove it. Go to app manager in your phone settings menu and disable the notification and then enable it back. This will remove the icon from the notification bar and from lock screen, but you will get the notification for new emails/events

Answer (score 0):

In Android Lollipop 5.0.2,  under Notifications I could suppress notifications on lock screen, while still being able to see persistent status message in status bar (for example, Skype's status). This is what I wanted, so that owner information would still be visible on lock screen.

Answer (score 0):

In Android Marshmallow at least, you can block all notifications per-app. Go to Settings -> Sound & Notifications -> App Notifications, choose the app, and then select "Block All". This works great for apps like Adguard which seem to require a persistent notification.

Answer (score -1):

Go to accessibiliry. Turn OFF PERSIATANT NOTIFICATIONS. that will work.

Answer (score -3):

Under sound and notification settings/app notifications you can block notifications on an app by app basis